# Delimit Hydrographic Basin, based on a single river

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, arc-hydro

I find myself doing a hydrological study, where I have to delimit the river basin based on a single river (polyline).

I have the DEM where the river of my interest is, and I have the river as a shapefile, but generally when I have made the delimitation of basins in ArcGIS, I have done it based on a network of drainage, but not on the basis of a only river of interest.

Is there a tool in which you can do all the hydrological processing, to obtain as a result the river basin of a specific river?

Comment: How is single river different to a network of drainage? Anyway this is very basic. Convert river to raster and the rest is the same process

Comment: Do you know where I can download a DEM with a resolution of 10 x 10 mts?.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried for a single river, but for a single point which belongs to the river for example.

You can delineate the draining area to a point within the river using the DEM. I do this using the GRASS tools included in the QGIS pack r.watershed and r.water.outlet.